# Theme development: menu links a tabbed page with page jumps

Tags: theme-development, pages, navigation, tabs

This might sound like a basic question, but It is my first time developing for wordpress:

I am developing a theme, I need to have:

- A landing page with navigation menu
- Another page that the landing page redirects to on each navigation menu item clicked

I can have several tabs in the navigation menu;
So for example on main page let's say we have a navigation menu:

**Details |  About | contact**

I want when a user click on say for example: "Details" to change the page's main content (not header or footer) and display different tabs with content.

So **Details |  About | contact** should ALL point to the same **Page** along with a **#menuitem** append to url.

For example if user clicks **details**:

==> it should go to url:

```
host/permanent-page/#details
```

and so **Details**  tab will be loaded on page.

if user clicks **About**:

==> it should go to **same** url:

```
host/permanent-page/#about
```

and so **About** tab will be loaded on page.

How can I make this mechanism?:

- All pages point to same url
- the url will have #itemname appended to it

Any guidance/hints will be very helpful to know where to start.

Comment: You will want to look into WP's Permalinks.  You should never direct visitors to the index.php script directly.  WP uses rewrite rules to create URLs based on the options selected under Settings > Permalinks

Comment: What do you see as the difference between a real page and a WP page/tab?

Comment: @jdm2112 Yes i am using permalinks, but i want to direct all nav menu items to a same link: myhost/permanent-page. Also i was not able to add # to permalinks

Comment: @czerspalace until now i saw when i click on a WP page, it reloads the same page with different content. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: i will re-write the description maybe it will make it more clear

Comment: Yes WordPress content uses one page and decides what to load based on the query string. Sounds like for your scenario a couple options would be to create a page template with a custom query, or use AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds awful from an SEO perspective but you could do this:

**Note**

The reason ( I believe ) you'd have to do this in a query is because of the fact Wordpress doesn't by default have a "Page Archive" so you wouldn't be able to do this with changing some `.htaccess` and "easy-peasy" it's done... It would be a little more involved.

Create a page or page-template. From there you could create a new [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) that call all your pages or a group of pages. Loop through your pages and give each a specific `<div>` or `<h1>` with an ID of the page slug, then create your menu using the hash.

```
<?php
    $my_pages = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
    ) );

    if( $my_pages->have_posts() ) : 
?>
    <?php while( $my_pages->have_posts() ) : $my_pages->the_post(); ?>

        <div id="<?php echo $page->post_name; ?>" class="page-section">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div> <!-- class="page-section" -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What we get could look something like this:

```
<div id="about" class="page-section">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>Blah blah blah blah. . .</p>
</div> <!-- class="page-section" -->

<div id="details" class="page-section">
    <h1>Details</h1>
    <p>Blah blah blah blah. . .</p>
</div> <!-- class="page-section" -->

<div id="contact" class="page-section">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <p>Blah blah blah blah. . .</p>
</div> <!-- class="page-section" -->
```

Now whenever you go to `http://www.your-url.com/#contact` you'll jump down to the "Contact" section of that page since it has the same ID. This sort of menu is called a "Jump Menu" and it's what many websites, such as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_jump_blues_musicians) uses for it's large sections. If you go to that wikipedia link and click one of the characters in the Alphabet, you'll notice the page jump and the URL add a `#`. Finally to express how the menu would work here's a [JSFiddle of the actual Menu](http://jsfiddle.net/3a679w2h/2/).

So, according to that JSFiddle you now need to create a menu of `#page-slug`. You have a few options on how you want to do this which is entirely up to you. I've layed out these options in no particular order.

1. Create a new WP Nav Menu ( Appearances -> Menus ) and create a custom menu of `#page-slug` all by hand. This could be tedious and is only automated if you're paying somebody to do it.
2. Custom create your menu.

   1. You could create 1 [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) at the top of your page, loop through it to create your menu, [`rewind_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts), then run your query again to generate the page and it's contents.
   2. You could also use [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) which I think may be a bit redundant if you're going to run a [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) anyway.

Hopefully that gets your started or I've misinterpreted your question entirely ( which is entirely possible ) in which case lemme know!